# Saving a Sharp Promise to a variable returns pending

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise, buffer

I'm trying to resize an image from a base64 encoded string. I can do this using c in `nodejs`. `Sharp` works with Promises, so I know I have to do async methods. After resizing, I need to convert it back to a base64 string. I usually do this by converting an image to a buffer, using the `nodejs Buffer`, then use the '`toString()` method to convert it back to base64.

This is what my code looks like:

```
async function resizer(base64, width = 224, height = 224) {
  if (!base64) {
    throw console.error("not a base64 string")
  } else {
    const Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer
    let base64buffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64")
    const image = await sharp(base64buffer)
      .resize({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fit: sharp.fit.cover,
      })
      .rotate(90)
      .toBuffer()

    const newBase64 = image.toString("base64")

    return newBase64
  }
}
const resizedBase64 = resizer(base64Image).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
  return result
})
console.log(resizedBase64)
```

The function takes a base64 string as an argument. It then gets converted to a buffer and I let sharp do it's thing.I then return the the newly generated string. When I store it as a variable, however, it returns a `Promise {pending}`. When I just console.log inside the `.then()` callback, it does log the new base64 string.

Anyone know how to fix this? I need to use the new base64 later in the code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add an `await` to get the resolved value from the promise:

```
const resizedBase64 = await resizer(base64Image);
```

EDIT: What's important to understand here is that your `resizer` function contains some asynchronous code (from the Sharp library) which returns a promise. As such, your function will also always return a promise of the value, not the value itself, even if you use `await` inside it. The caller of your function will receive the promise and will have to await it to get its actual value.

When calling your function `resizer`, if you are not in an async context and cannot use `await` there are a couple of solutions available.
Solution 1: use an IIFE

```
(async() => {
  const resizedBase64 = await resizer(base64Image);
  console.log(resizedBase64);
  // the rest of your code goes here
})();
```

Solution2: declare an async function (basically the same as previous)

```
async main() => {
  const resizedBase64 = await resizer(base64Image);
  console.log(resizedBase64);
  // the rest of your code goes here
});

main();
```

Solution 3: place your code inside the `then` callback

```
resizer(base64Image).then((resizedBase64) => {
  console.log(resizedBase64);
  // the rest of your code goes here
});
```

Comment: doing this results in a syntax error: "`const resizedBase64 = await resizer(base64Image)
                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: Yes, you can only use `await` inside an `async` function unless you use NodeJS > 14.8 as it supports top-level await. If you don't have top-level await support, you could use an IIFE like:
`(async () => {
  const resizedBase64 = await resizer(base64Image);
  console.log(resizedBase64);
})()`

Comment: I'm using NodeJS V 16.13. 

I've tried to use an async function before, but it's the same issue :( Your solution works, but this does not solve the issue where I have to use the actual string later on.

Comment: Either all your code goes into the IIFE, or it goes inside the `then` callback.

Comment: Well, what do you suggest then? The goal is that the function returns a base64 string. Right now, it does (when console.log), but I cannot use it as a variable. It keeps giving the 'pending' state

Comment: That's just how promises work... I edited my answer to provide different solutions. You have to understand that a function that returns a Promise needs to be awaited in order to get its resolved value. This can be achieved either through a `then` callback or with the keyword `await`

Comment: Yea I know. Thanks for the proposed solutions! I have tried it tho. The thing is, I need to export this function and then use it's output (returned value) as a value (in a key-value json). Does this mean that won't work?

Comment: What you have to understand is that a function containing some asynchronous code will always return a Promise, there is no working around it. So yes, exporting your function will work but it will return a Promise of the value, not the value itself. In the code that imports your function, you will have to await the promise

Comment: Thank you Ben! :) That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: You're welcome. I added the last bit of explanation to the answer for you to validate.